# SQL query: How to validate the prerequisite for courses that finished and how to find time conflict of courses?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

Am  trying to write query   that advise student what  courses  to register . The query  will select  the suitable courses and will validate  1)  the courses they finished .and what  left   for them  to take 2) The prerequisite courses to be finished .3) validate the time conflict. In order to recommend for him best courses.

I did those table and join them , but the join operation is not working . What syntax is the correct ?What if there are no prerequisite how i will check that ?some prerequisite are for senior or junior is that need separate table?

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MYSQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'studyplan sp on (t.std_id=sp.std_is)
left outer join prerequsit p on (p.preid = c.' at line 3

```
     select c.*
    from std t
   inner join schedule22  c studyplan sp
   on (t.std_id=sp.std_id)
   left outer join prerequsit p
   on (p.preid=c.courseid)
   inner join schedule22 c
   on (c.courseid=p.courseid)
   where t.std=1 AND
   sp.complated='No' AND
   sp.passed='No' AND
   p.preid=courseid;
```

Student

```
enter code here

  std_id       username    pass   fname     email


   1             hjh                154     jdf         example@live.com



    Studyplan

  Courseid   code  `prerequisite        std_id    completed    passed
   2       UNS 100   No Prerequisite     1         Y             Y
     3,   'ENG 100',   'No Prerequisite',    1, 'Y', 'Y'),
     5,  'MTT 101',   'MTG 100',   1, 'Y', 'Y'),
     6, 'MTT 202',   'MTT 101', 1, 'Y', 'N'),
    (7, 'STT 100', 'No Prerequisite', 1, 'N', 'N'),
    (8, 'MTT 102','MTT 101', 1, 'N', 'N'),
    (9, 'ENG 200','english1', 1, 'N', 'N'),
    (10, 'OE1',3, 'NULL', 1, 'N', 'N'),
    (11, 'ENG 201','ENG 200', 1, 'N', 'N'),
    (12, 'CSC 302', 'MTT 202', 1, 'N', 'N'),
    (13, 'STT 201',, 'STT 100', 1, 'N', 'N'),
    (15, 'CSC 201','MTT 101 or MTT 102', 1, 'N', 'N'),
    (16, 'CSC 202', 'CSC 201', 1, 'N', 'N'),
    (17, 'PSY 201', 'ENG 100 + UNS 100', 1, 'N', 'N'),
    (18, 'NSC 201', 'No Prerequisite', 1, 'N', 'N'),
    (19, 'CSC 307', 'CSC 201', 1, 'N', 'N'),
   (20, 'CSC 301','CSC 202', 1, 'N', 'N'),
   (21, 'ITE 390', 'Junior Level', 1, 'N', 'N'),
   (22, 'CSC 305', 'Junior Level', 1, 'Y', 'Y'),
   (23, 'ITE 305', ' 'Junior Level', 1, 'Y', 'Y'),
   (24, 'ITE 414', ', 'junior Level', 1, 'Y', 'Y'),
   (25, 'CSC 308',  'CSC 301', 1, 'N', 'N'),
   (26, 'ITE 402', 'CSC 305', 1, 'N', 'N'),
  (27, 'CSC 311', 'CSC 201', 1, 'N', 'N'),
  (28, 'ITE 422',  'CSC 305', 1, 'N', 'N'),
 (29, 'CIS 401',  'CSC 302', 1, 'N', 'N'),
 (30, 'ITE 409',  'Senior Level', 1, 'N', 'N'),
 (31, 'CIS 401',  'CSC 302', 1, 'N', 'N'),
 (32, 'CSC 401', 'ITE 305', 1, 'N', 'N'),
 (33, 'ITE 409', 'Null', 1, 'N', 'N'),
  (34, 'ITE 408',  'CSC 305', 1, 'N', 'N')
```

Schedule

```
enter code here

 semester`, `courseid`, `coursecode`, `section`,`date`, `time`, `,`sch_id`) 
  ('fall', 9, 'ENG 100', 51,'MoWe', '1:45PM-3:15PM', 'staff',1),
  ('fall', 16, 'CSC202', 51, 'Mo-We',' 1:45PM-3:15PM', 'staff',1),
  ('fall', 26, 'ITE402', 51, 'Tu','10:30-12pm', 'staff',1),
  ('fall', 6, 'MTT 202', 51,'Su-Tu', '12:00-2:00PM', 'staff',1),
  ('fall', 8, 'MTT 102', 51','SuTu',' 12:00-2:00PM', 'staff',1),
  ('fall', 12, 'CSC 302', 51,'Mo-We',' 10:00-12:00PM', 'staff',1),
  ('fall', 15, 'CSC 201', 52,'Mo-We',' 10:00-12:00PM', 'staff',1),
  ('fall', 21, 'ITE 390', 51, 'Su-Tu',' 12:00-2:00PM', 'staff',1),
  ('fall', 5, 'MTT 101', 51, 'Su',' 4:00PM -7:00PM', 'staff',1),


   ('fall', 28, 'ITE 422', 51, Su-Tu',' 12:00-2:00PM', 'staff',1);
```

prerequsit`

```
enter code here

    (`courseid`, `preid`) VALUES
       (5, 1,),
       (6, 2),
       (8, 3),
      (9, 4),
       (11, 5),
      (12, 6),
      (13, 7),
      (14, 8),
     (15, 9),
      (16, 10),
     (17, 11),
    (18, 12),
     (19, 13),
    (20, 14),
    (21, 21),
    (22, 22),
   (23, 23),
    (24, 24),
   (25, 20),
 (26, 22),
  (27, 25),
  (28, 22),
  (29, 12),
  (30, 30),
 (32, 23),
  (34, 22,),
  (35, 12),
  (36, 22),
  (37, 3),
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query contains `schedule22 c` twice in the from clause.  That's an error.  There may be more.